# Free IOS 'scan' app

Tags: gratis, ios, camera, optimization, scanning

I am looking for a *free* app that allows me to take pictures of documents ('scans'), and the app optimizes it.

I would like it:

- to be free
- to save in **color**
- to auto-optimize
- to allow me to crop it
- export to image and PDF
- auto/manual 'perspective' (?) fix

By perspective, I mean it should look straight even if I took it at a slight angle.

I don't care if it is:

- ad-supported, or
- flooded with in-app purchases

as long the above features are in the free version.

Comment: Native document scan functionality available since iOS 13 using Files and Notes might be handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Evernote Scannable](https://evernote.com/products/scannable/)

Evernote Scannable is a free iOS app that scans documents, fixing perspective and enhancing the result. It is very quick to scan documents and can be set up to automatically scan documents that it detects are placed in front of the camera.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Scanbot](https://appsto.re/fr/p3TWX.i) should fit your needs just fine.

The basic free version can capture documents with automatic cropping and perspective correction, the premium version adds OCR and cloud export capabilities.

[image: screenshot]

(screenshot of a lottery ticket scanned automatically, I didn't even need to press the trigger as the app automatically captures the document when light and focus are good enough)

Comment: Great app! +1. I like how you can pay to have OCR features, but @grgargside answered first, and it is unlikely I'll be paying in the future :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ the most important reason why not to pay for OCR is that they're still quite unreliable and never produce good enough results. (:

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Scanner Mini from Readdle and I'm really happy with it:

https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/scanner-mini-dokumente-rechnungen/id581365763

It even offers OCR, and it'S really stable for a free app.